# How to intercept connection to a Wifi network most efficiently on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, wifimanager

I want to perform some action when the phone connects to a certain WiFi network.
As far as I can see I have 2 Broadcast intent to intercept that will satisfy this:
1. Wifi State Changed.
2. Connectivity Changed.

The problem however is that I want to intercept ONLY the Wifi Connected events.
Currently my Receiver is triggered on any change to the WiFi, including disconnection, which I don't really care about.I feel it is a waste of CPU time.

Are there any more specific intents, like "Wifi Connected"?
Or alternatively, can I add something to the intent filter to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can say, there is no way to filter the intent `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` by state (Connected / Disconnected) or by network name.

Too bad :(

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the type of a network event by requesting his extra informations. First, make sure that you registered an `IntentFilter` on the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` action and bind it to a proper `BroadcastReceiver`.

Then in the receiver's `onReceive` method, you can check if the received event is a [`NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html) event :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
  NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

  if (networkInfo != null 
     && networkInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ) {
     // Do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but it does not answer the question. I don't want my receiver to be invoked on every change to the network state.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as you are limited to the event Android exposes. Regarding the wireless features, you need to know before receiving a `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` that it is a `NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED`.